# $X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$ and $X \perp Y \mid Z$ implies $X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Z$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I've been trying to prove this statement by opening up things on the left hand side using the chain rule but am really getting nowhere. Any tips/hints would be very helpful and appreciated!

Comment: What do all these symbols mean? Independence?

Comment: yeah, independence. sorry, thought that was clear :(

Comment: A friendly advice: [title is NOT the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet: the question post should be comprehensible without the title, even though one should make good use of the title to provide extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elementary argument, using an obvious notation. Notice how it mirrors @d.k.o's measure-theoretic proof.
$$
p(x,y)=\sum_z p(x,y\mid z)p(z) \stackrel{(1)}= \sum_z p(x\mid z)p(y\mid z)p(z)\stackrel{(2)}=p(x)\sum_zp(y\mid z)p(z)=p(x)p(y)
$$
In (1) we use the conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$; in (2) we assume independence of $X$ and $Z$, from which we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ must be independent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X$ is independent of $Z$. Then if $X$ is independent of $Y$ conditionally on $Z$ implies that 
$$
\mathsf{E}[f(X)g(Y)]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[f(X)g(Y)\mid Z]]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[f(X)\mid Z]\mathsf{E}[g(Y)\mid Z]]=\mathsf{E}[f(X)]\mathsf{E}[g(Y)]
$$
for any measurable functions $f$ and $g$ for which the relevant expectations exists (i.e. the unconditional independence of $X$ and $Y$).